# Idiomatic way to delete object from enclosing ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController which manages a group of objects. I define an itemController on this, so that each individual object is managed by another ObjectController:

```js
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: "sampleModel"
});
```

Inside this ObjectController, I have a `delete` action that is meant to delete objects from the enclosing array, using the "parent" ArrayController:

```js
App.SampleModelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  delete: function() {
    this.get("target.content").removeObject(this.get("content"));
  }
});
```

I don't want to have a global object store. I'm currently using the `target` property in order to achieve this kind of behaviour. Is this the idiomatic ember approach?

The complete example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vzfcK/2/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the delete function to the ArrayController. This way makes sense because the array controller is managing the collection. The way you have it works, but it doesn't seem right because your object is managing the array that it belongs to, which just seems like an awkward way of writing it.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: "sampleModel",

  delete: function(object) {
    this.get('content').removeObject(object)
  }
});

App.SampleModelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D22tH/)

Comment: I wasn't aware that it is possible to have parameters in handlebars' actions, hence my "dirty" solution.